# SQL Select Case with DB update

Tags: sql, select

I have the Gta_db database, with the Registrab_db table.
In this table I have the columns, "DataEntrada"; "datafinal" and "Trabalho".

depending on the type of "Trabalho", I want it to add a value to the entry date and to put that value at the "Datafinal".

I already did this and worked ...

```
SELECT CASE Trabalho
          When 'Averiguação' THEN DATEADD(day,10, DataChegada)
          When 'D. Simples' THEN DATEADD(day,5, DataChegada)
       END AS DataFinal
FROM RegisTrab_db
```

But I can't put it in a Trigger to update automatically

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: ... and add the language too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server (as the syntax suggests), don't use a trigger!  Use a computed column:

```
alter table RegisTrab_db
    add DataFinal as (case Trabalho
                         when 'Averiguação' then dateadd(day, 10, DataChegada)
                         when 'D. Simples' then dateadd(day, 5, DataChegada)
                      end);
```

This is calculated when the table is queried.  The calculation is always up-to-date, based on the contents of the table.

You would use a trigger if you simply wanted to initialize the value to this expression -- and then you want to change it to something else.  There is actually a way to handle that without a trigger as well, by introducing an `orderride_datafinal` column whose value is initially `NULL`:

```
alter table RegisTrab_db
    add DataFinal as (case when override_datafinal is not null then overrid_datafinal
                           when Trabalho = 'Averiguação' then dateadd(day, 10, DataChegada)
                           when Trabalho = 'D. Simples' then dateadd(day, 5, DataChegada)
                      end);
```

Comment: but this way it will add a new column right? I already have the columns all defined in datagridview ..... VBA gives error because, as I understand it, it is creating the column "DataFinal"
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'DataFinal' in table 'RegisTrab_db' is specified more than once. '

Comment: @NunodeFreitas . . . You can remove the column that is already there or give the computed column a different name.

Comment: It worked!!!!! thank you very much
However, I have another problem.
I have built the datagridview inside VBA.

When I am going to change any kind of data, after doing Drop and Add, I have a bug in VBA.                  "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The column "DataFinal" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.'

Comment: @NunodeFreitas . . . This question is about adding a column with a particular value to a table -- and this answers your question.  If you have a different question, ask that as a *new* question.